# How to update rows using where condition in MsGraph Excel API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

I am trying to do an update to a specific rows using Microsoft Graph API for Excel. Browsing through the documentation and googling, could't found out any way of working with the API to do an update like using a "where" query.

I have tried `/filter/apply` couple with `/range/visibleView/rows`, and was able to query like a where condition.

However, the index(rows) in `patch` uses absolute index value in the excel and not the current visibleView. Thus, I am not able to directly update a specific rows knowing what is the unique key that can use a "where" query.

Kind of defeat the purpose, if we have to query the whole table just to get the index for the update purpose, when the record list is huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.

`visibleView` come along with `cellAddresses`. In which we can use it to the row of the cell.

Subsequently, can use that index to call the `PATCH /tables/{table}/rows/$/ItemAt(index={index})`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Don't forget to check your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works!
Also Sample Payload format for those who don't know - 

`{"values":[["Val. in Column 1","Val. in Column 2","Val. in Column 3",]]}`